# Russians leaving Russia (during covid times)

Tags: covid-19, mexico, russian-citizens

Does anyone know if it's possible to leave Russia (as a russian national) without:

1. having a medical reason
2. having a family member
3. having a spouse or concubine
4. having a work or work offer

in the target destination / country you're trying to get to. In this case, Mexico.

I've read online that some people went to Belarus first but that it's currently closed now because of the protests.

Anyone know (or better yet, have successfully employed) other possibilities/routes?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Turkey and UK as of early Sep 2020. They're officially ["Open"](https://tass.ru/obschestvo/9158577).

In fact there's a huge number of flights going to Turkish resorts from Russia, without needing any more reason.

So, you should probably just arrange a layover in Istanbul.

Comment: is there any source to this? all info I can find online talks about people going to Russia via Turkey but not the opposite

Comment: ah I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niR6DTjxCzE&ab_channel=TRTWorld

Comment: Would you know anything about using paris as a stop on the way to Mexico? if not 'entering the european space' per se, staying within the airport transit-bounds and boarding the flight to MX, should there be any issues? Somebody linked me to a french consulate document mentioning this was ok but I can't find the link.

Comment: I think this merits a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Study is another valid reason to exit Russia according to the governmental website http://government.ru/en/docs/39842/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200904040657/http://government.ru/en/docs/39842/)):

> Russian citizens can leave the country to attend to close relatives abroad who need care. The same applies to those who need to go abroad for medical treatment as well as to work or **study**.